# How to wrap NHibernate QueryOver API

Tags: wrapper, queryover

I wrapped Nhibernate session as the following.

```
public interface IDalSession : IDisposable
{
    void MarkForRollBack();
    void End();
    IDalSession Start();
    IDalSession StartWithTransaction();
    T Save<T>(T entity);
    T CreateQuery<T>(string query);
    //ISession GetHibernateSession { get; }
}
```

I really want to use QueryOver as my main query.
QueryOver API looks impossible to be wrapped because it is huge. 
One solution is to use the NHibernate `ISession` (`GetHibernateSession`) in all of the places I need to pull data. but it is very ugliy.
What is the workaround here? 
How can I wrap QueryOver?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
    public interface IDalSession : IDisposable
    {
        void MarkForRollBack();
        void End();
        IDalSession Start();
        IDalSession StartWithTransaction();
        T Save<T>(T entity);
        T CreateQuery<T>(string query);
        IQueryOver<T,T> NewQueryOver<T>(); // check me out
        //ISession GetHibernateSession { get; }
    }

    ...

     public IQueryOver<T,T> NewQueryOver<T>()
        {

          return Session.QueryOver<T>();
        }
```

You may get some comments about hiding away anything NH from other layers, so for that its fine to be able to pass back a new linq to NH query as its `IQueryable`:

```
 public virtual IQueryable<T> NewQuery<T>()
    {
      return Session.Query<T>();
    }
```

but I personally prefer QueryOver API so I wrap my data access into concrete repositories. S#arp architecture does it nice:

- [Interface](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/source/browse/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Core/PersistenceSupport/IRepository.cs?spec=svn353&r=353)
- [Impl.](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/source/browse/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Data/NHibernate/Repository.cs?r=493)

Comment: Perfect!!! Exactly, I wanted to hide NH and it seems that `Session.Query<T>();` helps. thanks